# How do I get a NuGetGallery running on IIS from scratch?

Tags: iis, nuget

I am trying to setup a [NuGet Gallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery) on my workstation to play around with, but I can't seem to get the prerequisites or configuration in order. I had a [problem building](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/120) the source, but I think I solved that. I was able to run it in WebMatrix/IIS Express, but I want to "upgrade" and get it running in full IIS.

What are the simplest steps to follow to get a local NuGet Gallery running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps that ended up working for me were...

1. Install ASP.NET MVC (from the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx))
2. Register ASP.NET v4.0 (`cmd> aspnet_regiis.exe -i`)
3. Download [NuGetGallery](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery) and build it
4. Put the website output somewhere on your disk
5. Create a new website in IIS pointed to that output (use the `DefaultAppPool`)
6. Change the `DefaultAppPool` to use .NET 4.0
7. Change the `DefaultAppPool` identity to `NetworkService` (use Advanced Settings)
8. Create a SQLEXPRESS database named “NuGetGallery”
9. Create a login for `NetworkServic`e on the SQLEXPRESS instance (with sysadmin privileges?)
10. Recycle the app pool, restart the website

You’re ready to run your website! You probably want to pick a cool address like, `nuget.mycompany.com` or `mycompany.com/nuget`.